# Ant waitfor is waiting longer than it needs to

Tags: ant

I'm using Ant to wait until a URL is accessible before running an exec task, but it is waiting for far longer than I want it to.

My `waitfor` -

```
<waitfor maxwait="3" maxwaitunit="minute" checkevery="500">
    <http url="http://127.0.0.1:${product.listenport}/start/"/>
</waitfor>
```

Almost as soon as I see this output on the terminal, I load the URL in the browser and get the page as expected, and still Ant waits (probably longer than the `maxwait` value even).

Is there a problem with this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to insert a short delay (just a few seconds should be enough, by the sound of it) before the first check.  I suspect Ant is making its first attempt to fetch the URL too soon and hanging for some reason *during* that first fetch (before `waitfor` gets a chance to wait half a second and try again).

```
<sleep seconds="5" />
<waitfor maxwait="3" maxwaitunit="minute" checkevery="500">
    <http url="http://127.0.0.1:${product.listenport}/start/"/>
</waitfor>
```

Comment: That seems logical, but unfortunately a wait doesn't help. The waitfor just keeps timing out. I've added the timeoutproperty and verified thats what happens. My current solution is to just minimise the maxwait because so far, the server is available.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too just now. I was trying to use waitfor as a sort of ping

Some of our unit tests require a database connection to perform them properly and we have that database on a company server. I don't want the tests to try and run if I'm not connected to that server because those tasks just hang waiting for the server and I can't tell if it is running the tests or just waiting for a connection.  By the time I realize the latter a fair amount of wasted time has passed. I have to connect to the server and then rerun the tests. So I was looking for a quick sort of Ping task that would fail if not connected to the server.  Here is my solution.

```
<limit maxwait="10" maxwaitunit="second" failonerror="true">
   <waitfor maxwait="20" maxwaitunit="second">
      <socket server="myserver" port="5432"/>
    </waitfor>
</limit>
```

Port 5432 is for postgresql, but you can check whichever port is appropriate for your task.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `checkeveryunit` to your block, it should do the trick, something like that:

```
<waitfor maxwait="3" maxwaitunit="minute" checkevery="5" checkeveryunit="second">
   <http url="http://127.0.0.1:${product.listenport}/start/"/>
</waitfor>
```

This way you will not wait for 500 seconds and pass the `maxwait`